# AppleScript vs. AutoIt

Tags: scripting, applescript, autoit

I get the sense that AppleScript is more respected than AutoIt. I think that it's something you can put on your resume whereas AutoIt is not. Is that the case? Why is that? With AutoIt you can automate just about anything. Is that the case with AppleScript? With AppleScript can you make it detect arbitrary images on the screen like images in a web page?

Comment: Actually AutoHotKey is a clone of AutoIt and AutoIt more popular outside of lifehacker. http://www.google.com/trends?q=autoit%2C+autohotkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both languages serve very different purposes. They both started out with similar goals in mind, but evolved differently over the years.

AutoIt has adapted GUIs and has become more of a general purpose scripting language. It also has a large following of developers that all contribute to the functionality of the language. Applescript focuses mostly on what AutoIt was originally designed for, automation.

What really separates them on this focus is that AutoIt interacts based on commands and properties of Windows, where as Applescript interacts based on commands and properties of the application it is automating. Applescript is more similar to OOP, where as AutoIt is a traditional procedural language.

Why one is more popular than the other? that is a difficult question. I actually learned about AutoIt years before I knew anything about Applescript, but that is because I worked primarily on Windows and Linux machines and rarely on Macs. It really isn't a fair comparison to say one is more popular than the other, as there is no common element between them.

Windows users will know AutoIt, Mac users will know Applescript.

Answer (score 6):

AutoIt had a big role in getting me my current job. If you get an interview with a team of developers, bringing something new to the table is not a bad thing. Sure you are not going to find "AutoIt Developer Needed" in the want ads, but more companies need one then know it. My use of AutoIt has turned into something that sets me apart from other developers in my work.

Picking the right tool for the job is what matters and for some jobs that tool is undoubtedly AutoIt. Most developers would be excited to see something they don't know on the resume of an applicant. It tells you several things.

1. This person is going to bring something unique to the team.
2. This person is into programming because they surely didn't learn AutoIt from a required class to get their degree.
3. Most people who love development are going to want to talk about this odd language you know that they have never heard of. If you have some example code that would be a pain in another language you have a good shot at impressing them.

It worked for me. While you are not likely to work full time as an AutoIt developer, I use it several times a week in my work.

Comment: Having AutoIt on my resume also helped me land the job I currently have because the hiring manager had some working knowledge of AutoIt, and he had written some utilities in AutoHotKey.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you asking here?

AppleScript is likely more widely known than AutoIt (I never heard of AutoIt and just had to look it up).  Whether that means it's more "respected" or "you can put it on your resume" is entirely subjective.

The two seem to be very different things.  For what reason are you comparing/contrasting them?  If you're looking for which one to use for any given purpose, the first important factor would be the platform.  They're designed to run on very different platforms.

There may be some things you can do in one that you can not do (at least natively or without great difficulty) in the other.  The same is true of just about any drastically different programming/scripting tools/environments.

Comment: It seems strange to me that AppleScript is more well known, since AutoIt does more than AppleScript and it runs on Windows, which most people have.

Comment: Market share has nothing to do with it. AutoIt is a Windows-only tool and Applescript is on the Mac. As someone who works solely on Macs, I had never heard of AutoIt either.